# Pandas read_fwf difficulty interpreting a date-like string

Tags: python, pandas, date

Pandas read_fwf difficulty interpreting a date-like string

I'm reading several hundred fixed width files into a postgresql database parsing it using pandas read_fwf code.

My stumbling block is trying to pull the end date from the period from the last ten columns of one of the lines.

An example file can be found at this [link](ftp://ftp.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/htdocs/products/analysis_monitoring/cdus/degree_days/archives/Cooling%20Degree%20Days/weekly%20degree%20days%20city/2016/Sep%2024,%202016.txt) at the NOAA website:

The critical code snippet from my Python/pandas script:

```
import os
import time
import requests
import pandas as pd
import time
import datetime
from dateutil.parser import *

## Load adapters
import psycopg2
import psycopg2.extensions

df = pd.read_fwf(ddFname, header=None, )

if str(df[0:1]).find('COOLING') >= 0:
    amtType = 'CDD'
elif str(df[0:1]).find('HEATING') >= 0:
    amtType = 'HDD'

prDate = str(df[3:4])[-10:-1]
print(prDate)
```

When I invoke the last line I get the following:

```
SEP 24,...
```

when I need the following:

```
SEP 24, 2016
```

Much thanks for any and all help.

Comment: Given that you're reading it via fwf, and based on the input file, it looks like `2016` has been fitted into the next column. Perhaps, `df[3:5]` instead of `df[3:4]`

Answer (score -1):

Using the example file you posted. The following works for me:

```
df = pd.read_fwf(ddFname, header=None, )
str(df.at[4, 0])[-12:]
# Out[99]: 'SEP 24, 2016'
```

When you do something like:

```py
str(df[3:5])
```

You are invoking the [`__repr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr) method of a pandas DataFrame. The repr method often truncates large cells for readability (as it does in this case). For this case it looks like:

```py
repr(df[3:5])
Out[106]: '                                                   0    1\n3                                                NaN  NaN\n4  LAST DATE OF DATA COLLECTION PERIOD IS SEP 24,...  NaN'
```

and `str(_)[-10:-1]` gives:

```py
Out[107]: '4,...  Na'
```

The indexes between your file and mine aren't quite matching up, but hopefully you understand better what's going on here. Using `at` will access the actual value at a particular row and column (the value won't be truncated).